# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: Unknown command-line option '-X'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio 1.5.1 I am getting this error. I searched but wasn't able to identify what's causing this error.

Removed all command-line option still getting error.

Checked all xml files for any errors. Still no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I also meet this issue,lucky I find the reason.
open your as.
Setting->compiler

[image: command line options]

Be sure this is empty, your gradle will be ok

Answer (score 2):

Follow the process below:

1. Open the `android studio`
2. File > setting > Build, execution and deployment > compiler
3. clear the command line text and then click apply n ok
4. click on make project button or simply press [Ctrl+F9]

[image: See the image]